# How to map an image into react components or vectors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, vectorization, simulator

I have to reproduce a map of the train rails of a city for a simulator / web-app built in spring boot / react. The map is quite complicated and each rail is divided into lots of small areas that light up in white or red when a train is passing, so I need to turn each area into a react components that can change color or something like that. Thankfully the UI doesn't need to be smooth or to have 60 fps because the main purpose of the simulator is to control an optical control panel.

I got the map in .tif or .jpeg format, any idea how I could reproduce this map automatically with a tool or a lib ? I was thinking about vectorizing the map image into an SVG, but then I need to be able to change the colors of some parts of the SVG individually. Is this possible with react or just pure JS ?

Thanks !

Comment: You certainly need to transform your bitmap image into verctor (svg). So far, your question is way too broad and it's not really clear are you asking how to build a UI or how to do bitmap-to-vector conversion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated my post. Actually I'm asking if it's possible to vectorize an image automatically with a tool, and then if it's possible to modify this svg image dynamically.

Comment: You may [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+png+to+svg&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUA826UA826&oq=convert+png+to+svg&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.5864j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) online tools to *vectorize* your source image. However, in order to apply styles dynamically (by React.js, or whatever you will use), you'll need certain metadata attached to each segment, so there will be a lot of handwork needed. Instead, I would suggest to use some spatial software (e.g. QGIS) or any vector image editor of your choice to transform your image into proper set of segments with all the necessary attributes.